# Android reCAPTCHA API: What's the point of validating the user token?

Tags: android, recaptcha, safetynet

I'm investigating the new [Android reCAPTCHA API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha.html) but I am not really getting what is the point of validating the user token via `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` and why this isn't done automatically by the `SafetyNet` client.

Can someone explain why this is needed, what could happen if I don't do it and why isn't done already by the `SafetyNet` client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reCAPTCHA api on the client side (mobile phone) verifies the user and issues a token that needs to be validated.

Important to note this validation is done on the backend side (not client side) so think of it as a one time token to verify the user on >>your<< backend. 
reCAPTCHA stops the bots from automating the process as much as it can and one time token stops replay attacks if someone sniffs out a valid token somewhere.

So to summarize, you need to have your own backend that would do the reCAPTCHA token validation.

[image: Google reCAPTCHA summary]